# String Output in Pdcurses

Tags: c++, string, pdcurses

I am using **pdcurses** in C++ to program a game and am having some problems when trying to output a string.

Basically the relevant program is like this:

```
class Bunny {
private:
    string name;
public:
    string bgetname() { return name;};
}

class Troop {
private:
    vector<Bunny> bunpointer;  // bunpointer is a pointer to different bunnies
public:
    string getname(int i) {return bunpointer[i].bgetname();};
}

/* I create some bunnies in the troop which is pointed by bunpointer
 * troop is in class Troop
 */

int main() {
    Troop troop; // there will be 5 bunnies in the troop at the beginning
    initscr();
    // .....

    mvprintw(17,0,"%s was created!",troop.getname(1)); // <---- where problem is

    // .....
}
```

The program should output names of the bunnies in the troop, but it actually outputs some random characters like `<` or `u` or `@`....

My guess is that the `troop.getname` in `main()` may have some problems in pointing to the correct memory that stores the name of the bunnies, so the output are some irregular characters. But I cannot see why because I feel like the chain `mvprintw`--->`troop.getname()`--->`bunpointer.bgetname` is straightforward...

Comment: Your problems are elsewhere, not from what's show cased here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used pdcurses but it looks like mvprintw is similar to printf. So the %s means you're passing it a c-style string (const char*), but you give it a std::string. Try calling the c_str function on your std::string:

```
mvprintw(17,0,"%s was created!",troop.getname(1).c_str());
```